# ClosedXML generated file wont open in MS Spreadsheet Compare tool

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, openxml, closedxml

I'm trying to build new process to auto generate Excel files using ClosedXML (0.92.1). The very basic XLSX file will open in Excel just fine, but when I try to use the [MS tool Spreadsheet Compare tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-Spreadsheet-Compare-0E1627FD-CE14-4C33-9AB1-8EA82C6A5A7E), it can't open the file. The error we are getting is

*"Error opening workbook. Attempted to read past the end of the stream"*

If I open the ClosedXML generated file in Excel and save it first, the file can now be opened by the Spreadsheet Comparison tool. Excel is fixing/adding something to the file that is missing from ClosedXML.

I'm just using very basic code

```
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        workbook.Properties.Author = "Me";
        workbook.Properties.Title = "Title";
        var worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sheet 1");
        worksheet.Row(1).Cell(1).SetValue("test");
        workbook.SaveAs("c:\\temp\\testing.xlsx");
    }
```

The goal is to use the Spreadsheet comparison tool to make sure what we are generating is matching the old process that created the same file.

I ran the file the "Open and Repair" in the Excel file open dialog, and it gives me this report on the original file generated from ClosedXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<logFileName>error260080_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\TEMP\testing.xlsx'</summary>
<additionalInfo><info>Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.</info></additionalInfo>
</recoveryLog>
```

Comment: You state that Excel can open the file, but yet you can 'repair' it. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha The core properties are in a file `package/services/metadata/core-properties/{guid}.psmdcp` inside the ClosedXML-generated file instead of in `docProps/core.xml` like in an Excel-generated file. That seems to be the problem for the compare tool and probably comes from the OpenXML library, not ClosedXML.

Comment: Thanks @Raidri . It still blows my mind that you're not active on the project page itself.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha Too much to do and not enough time :(

Comment: @FrancoisBotha, yes Excel does load the original file, but you can still use the feature in Excel to "Open and Repair" on the file open dialog. That is where I got the hint something might not be right.

Comment: @nerdbrick Open an issue on the project page and complete the template FULLY and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha, I did some more research and found the base library OpenXML is causing the same issue. I have moved over to that team for more help. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fa395b57-ab12-4fe8-9fa1-0726c18fe0cd/openxml-generated-file-wont-open-in-ms-spreadsheet-compare-tool-and-excel-open-and-repair-also?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: @NerdBrick You might want to log the issue on the OpenXML page rather. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK . Of course they'd want a reproducible test cases that does NOT depend on ClosedXML.